# Correction of introductory IC analysis

Tags: syntax, syntax-trees

I've attempted an IC analysis of the following sentences and was wondering if anyone with a bit more experience would be able to help with corrections or suggestions.

**Having discussed it thoroughly, Harry and his girlfriend decided to take the classes on Monday.**

[S[AdvP Having discussed it thoroughly][NP/S Harry and his girlfriend][VP[V decided][S/Non-finite VPto take][NP the classes][PP on Monday]]]

**In London lies a knight a Pope interred.**

[S[PP/Premodifier In London][VP lies][NP/S a knight][S/Post-modifier a Pope interred]]

**After the breakfast dishes were put away, her mother silently thrust a brown paper parcel into her arms and ordered her outside.**

[S[PP/Sentence Modifier After [S/Object of Preposition the dishes were put away]][S[NP her mother][VP silently thrust [NP/DO a brown paper parcel][PP/Post-modifier  into her arms]] _/ and  _ [S[V/VP ordered][NP/OD her outside]]]]

Comment: I don't understand your use of / in the names of categories.  In some cases, where you write A/B, it seems to me that just A without the /B is closer to being right.  (In categorial grammar, A/B is the category of something which when combined with a B gives an A.)

Comment: A/B in this case would reference formal/functional labels.